# Attaching photo from iPhone while composing message with Gmail on desktop

Tags: gmail, mac, osx

I prefer to write mail on my desktop computer (Mac OS X), so I can use a real keyboard.

Often while writing such an email, I would like to attach a photo right where I am writing and take it with the camera on my iPod touch / iPhone. Is there a way to somehow communicate with the Mac for "insert a photo snapped from iOS here"? (Perhaps an app?)

In other words I would like to:

1. open Gmail on desktop Mac
2. start writing email
3. open some app on iOS and tap "snap photo"
4. photo automatically appears in the Gmail message I am writing on the computer

Comment: Since you're ensconced in the Apple ecosystem, this might be a better question for [apple.se].

Answer (score 1):

Just email the photo to yourself (it can also serve as a backup of that picture). Or you can connect your iPhone to your computer via a USB cable.

Or download a photo sharing app. Or use Dropbox.

But if you want it quick, use apps that share photo via a web browser (using an IP address and port). You can download the free iOS app [WiFi Photo Transfer](https://itunes.apple.com/sg/app/wifi-photo-transfer/id380326191?mt=8). No set up required, just a web browser (you **won't** need a Mac companion app too!).